# How to send a textbox to a printer

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, textbox

I am writing a program in Visual Basic, I want that users could print the contect of TextBox1.Text

This is my code part:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings
    PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = True
    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If
End Sub
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? is it not printing anything? take a look at this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811401 and this http://vbcity.com/forums/t/157103.aspx

Comment: The printed page is empty...

Comment: I would just save the text to a file (see snippets) then print it via wordpad to the default printer. write.exe /p filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually printing anything. [Have a look at this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx). It has a fully worked example of how to do printing.

Basically you need to put code into the `PrintDocument.PrintPage` Event.

For Exmaple:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim linesPerPage As Single = 0
    Dim yPos As Single = 0
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim leftMargin As Single = ev.MarginBounds.Left
    Dim topMargin As Single = ev.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim line As String = Nothing 

    ' Calculate the number of lines per page.
    linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics)

    ' Print each line of the file. 
    While count < linesPerPage
        line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()
        If line Is Nothing Then 
            Exit While 
        End If
        yPos = topMargin + count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics)
        ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos, New StringFormat())
        count += 1
    End While 

    ' If more lines exist, print another page. 
    If (line IsNot Nothing) Then
        ev.HasMorePages = True 
    Else
        ev.HasMorePages = False 
    End If 
End Sub
```